# exposing local website to the world using no-ip and local iis

Tags: iis, .net, windows, dyndns

I have web api service which I want to expose to the world.

So I created no-ip account, download it's client app, configured no-ip host name.

I then publish my web api project and create new website on my local iis using IIS Manager.

I am able to browse this website.

I also assign port on my website to 11992.

**Question is: why I am able to see this website on `http://localhost:11992` and not on `mywebiste.ddns.net:11992` ?**

Are there any other steps I should take in order to make this work?

Update:
My 11992 TCP port is not blocked by windows firewall. 
On my request ISP is assign me a public ip, so it's not static.

*is your PC connecting to the Internet using a router that is applying "NAT translations"?*

I guess, it's huawei router and I added port 11992 using NAT - Virtual Server option and using canyouseeme.org reports

**Success: I can see your service on xx.239.xx.58 on port (11992)
Your ISP is not blocking port 11992**
When I hit mywebsite.ddnes.net I'm getting router admin login (like I hit 192.168.1.1)
but when I'm try mywebsite.ddnes.net:11992 I'm getting 404 error

Comment: Is your 11992 TCP port being blocked/filtered by your windows firewall? Also: are you sure your ISP is assigning an IP address that, while **NOT** static, is "public" (or: if you ping mywebsite.ddns.net, the resolved IP is the same of the "ipconfig" output)? Also, is your PC connecting to the Internet using a router that is applying "NAT translations"? Please provide details.

Comment: @DamianoVErzulli thanks, question is updated and problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to browse to the site from the machine on which it is hosted. When you access it via `localhost`, the machine translates the hostname to the loopback address, `127.0.0.1`; when you access it via the fqdn, `mywebiste.ddns.net`, your machine translates the hostname to your WAN address (assuming you don't host a local DNS server).

To work around this, you can add an entry to the machine's **hosts** file (%windir%\system32\drivers\etc). Just add an entry for your site:

```
127.0.0.1    mywebsite.ddns.net
```

or for IPv6:

```
::1    mywebsite.ddns.net
```

Also, if you want to browse the site from other machines on your LAN, you will have to do the same thing on those machines, substituting host machine's LAN address for the loopback address (e.g. 192.168.1.xxx).

```
192.168.1.xxx    mywebsite.ddns.net
```